# AngularJS: is not a function TypeError

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use [jQuery Geocomplete](https://github.com/tmentink/jquery.geocomplete) with my AngularJS application.

I have this in my html page.

```
    <input id="destination-location-input" type="text" class="form-control"
     ng-model="destCtrl.destination" ng-change="destCtrl.locationChanged()" 
     data-geocomplete="street address" required/>
```

and added this code in controller.

```
var myElement = angular.element( document.querySelector('#destination-location-input'));    

myElement.geocomplete(
    {
      appendToParent: true,
      onChange: function(name, result) {
         var location = result.geometry.location;
      },
      onNoResult: function(name) {
         console.log("Could not find a result for " + name)
      }
    });
```

When run my app, I am getting this error.

> TypeError: myElement.geocomplete is not a function

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include the Google Maps API with the Places Library before loading this plugin as described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#loading_the_library)

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<script src="jquery.geocomplete.js"></script>
```

Comment: Those are included

Answer (score 0):

Use this;

```
var myElement = angular.element( document.querySelector('#destination-location-input'))[0];    

myElement.geocomplete(
{
  appendToParent: true,
  onChange: function(name, result) {
     var location = result.geometry.location;
  },
  onNoResult: function(name) {
     console.log("Could not find a result for " + name)
  }
});
```

Comment: are you use JQuery?

Comment: yeah. I am using JQuery

Comment: So Why you not write code like :
`$('#destination-location-input').geocomplete(
{
  appendToParent: true,
  onChange: function(name, result) {
     var location = result.geometry.location;
  },
  onNoResult: function(name) {
     console.log("Could not find a result for " + name)
  }
});`

Comment: Yeah. this works. but I am trying to use Angular way to obtain an element.